# Need help regarding CountDownTimer in onbackpressed

Tags: android

I have been trying to create the onbackpressed() function using countdown but i don't know what to do. Kindly help me to create the onbackpressed function using countdown

Answer (score 0):

private static boolean onbackpressonce = false;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}



// using countdown timer

     @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
      if (!onbackpressonce) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          onbackpressonce = true;
      } else {
          super.onBackPressed();
                    }

      new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

          @Override
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onFinish() {
              onbackpressonce = false;
          }
      }.start();

 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**This will exit your app on the second onBackpressed within 1100 millis**

```
private long mLastBackClick = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastBackClick < 1100) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press back again to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mLastBackClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```